# EPiServer - not rendering the custom property in Edit mode.

Tags: episerver, customproperty

I've been scratching my head bald regarding this issue and I am left blank.

I have a PageType, containing a custom property which is directly copied from the AlloyDemo.

```
    [BackingType(typeof(PropertyStringList))]
    [Display(Order = 305)]
    [UIHint(Global.SiteUIHints.Strings)]
    [CultureSpecific]
    public virtual string[] Address { get; set; }
```

The BackingType PropertyStringList class looks like this:

```
[EditorHint(Global.SiteUIHints.Strings)]
[PropertyDefinitionTypePlugIn(Description = "String List", 
DisplayName = "String List")]
public class PropertyStringList : PropertyLongString
{
    protected String Separator = "\n";

    public String[] List
    {
        get
        {
            return (String[])Value;
        }
    }

    public override Type PropertyValueType
    {
        get
        {
            return typeof(String[]);
        }
    }

    public override object SaveData(PropertyDataCollection properties)
    {
        return LongString;
    }

    public override object Value
    {
        get
        {
            var value = base.Value as string;

            if (value == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            return value.Split(Separator.ToCharArray(),        
    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        }
        set
        {
            if (value is String[])
            {
                var s = String.Join(Separator, value as String[]);
                base.Value = s;
            }
            else
            {
                base.Value = value;
            }

        }
    }

    public override IPropertyControl CreatePropertyControl()
    {
        //No support for legacy edit mode
        return null;
    }
}
```

When I run the site, it renders (in Edit mode) the property Address like this:

[Rendering fail, which is a button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3ow5.png)
And when I click the button I get this:
[Null Reference Exception in a popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6c24.png)

**I seriously have no clue why this is happening. Could somebody explain?**

Regards, Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the editor descriptor. Check out "StringListEditorDescriptor.cs" in the Alloy project. You'll also need the client resources -the StringList dojo script. And you also need to register this module.config

Comment: You are absolutely right, I totally had forgotten about the Editor Descriptor. Thank you!